# How to execute only one thread and receive a Future without creating an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, future, executorservice

I need to execute only a a single thread with the ability to cancel it. I found that I can achieve this using `Future<T>`s. Right now I use it like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(copyCallable);
executorService.shutdown();
```

Since `ExecutorService`s are usually used to manage a multiple threads, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to achieve this without creating one. Thanks.

Comment: `ExecutorService` won't help in canceling created thread, you'll have to manage that yourself. As far as waiting for output is concerned, you can just call `new thread().join()` in the caller thread.

Comment: In android class [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is made for this. usually only one AsyncTask is executed outside the gui thread at a time and AsyncTask.onPostExecute is executed in the gui thread when the AsyncTask.doInBackground() is finished.

Comment: Why do you care whether or not it is _efficient_?  Doing it the way you did looks like an efficient use of _your_ time.  Anything else will only force you to write more lines of code, and maybe force some other programmer to read more lines of code some day.  Is the performance of your program unsatisfactory?  If not, then why not just stop where your are and be happy with it?

Comment: @11thdimension I was assuming that `future.cancel(true)` will magically stop the thread even if doesn't explicitly handle cancelling. After some research I figured out I need to handle the cancel myself in the `Callable` or just use a regular thread and handle the interrupt myself. I think the latter approach is more efficient than creating an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @k3b This operation is long running, hence I opted to create my own thread.

Comment: @jameslarge There was a slight delay( ~ 1s blocking of the UI thread) while this thread was starting up, hence I assumed the overhead was associated with creating the `ExecutorService` and then submitting a `Callable` to it.

Comment: The overhead may be associated with creating the thread.  You said you needed "only a single thread," but if you meant you _frequently_ need a single thread, then don't shut the `ExecutorService` down:  Keep it, and re-use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interryprion is implemented by both Thread and calling method. Your thread need to listen for InterruptedException or check interruption flag at convenient points in time. Calling code should call t.interrupt() for notifying Thread that it should stop.

Comment: This is the was to go, I was using `Future` only for the ability to `cancel()` which I still have to handle, just like a plain `Thread`, might as well use a regular thread. Thanks!